# What are the defaults of route metrics?

Tags: networking, route, metric

I was trying to script OpenVPN server setup to modify metric of pushed routes so these are higher than any other interface:

```
push "route-metric 700"
```

This is needed to overcome https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/ticket/1004 bug.

Though 700 seems to be high enough since I've seen 600 to be used for the wireless interface at least on my system.

But where are these defaults stored or hardcoded in the system (for different interface types) so I can parse this value and increment of at least so that I'm sure that 700 metric is enough?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re seeing 600 for the route metric on a wireless interface, I’m guessing you’re using Network Manager. In that case, you’ll find the default route metrics for each device type in [`src/devices/nm-device.c`’s `nm_device_get_route_metric_default` function](https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/master/src/devices/nm-device.c#L1779). The highest metric you’ll see in practice is 750 for Bluetooth, or perhaps 800 for Open vSwitch.